Best Practice Redirect
Google has added sub-listing links to the search results for our brand. Issue is one links to example.com/shoes and displays all shoes nationally so its not ideal for user. I'm at a loss to select best practice to avoid this:

A folder redirect to homepage. The website's main content is within the folder /shoes/ - would those urls be at risk of redirection also?
Instead redesign page example.com/shoes to show links for cities that user can click on?
A 404 page if user navigates to "example.com/shoes"?


There are a few solutions.

Tag it as noindex so that it doesnt get indexed.
Default it to a search. Detect there are no params and default to something.
Submit to Google with a default param and mark canonical to the page with this param.

Its upto you.
